# How can i show empty record label error when using repeater control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have client request where there will be 3 columns out of these 3 columns,if any one column data is empty i need to show empty label error in that particular column.i want to use repeater control only please tell me guys how can i handle this my front end code is below and i don't know how to handle from code behind please help

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_ClientSection" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="serviceBox">
                <i class="service-icon fa fa-globe"></i>
                <h4 class="title"><%#Eval("Client_Name")%></h4>
                <p class="description"><%#Eval("Client_Details")%></p>
                <a href="#" class="read-more">
                    <span>Read More</span>
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

[1]: https://ibb.co/48kF0Sz want to implement like this image

Answer (score 0):

You could do a ternary operator in the ItemTemplate

```
<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Client_Name").ToString()) ? Eval("Client_Name") : "EMPTY" %>
```

Comment: this only gives result for single data i need for 3 columns